# How do you force drupal 7 to make a new revision every time you edit a node?

Tags: 7, nodes

I'd like to make drupal 7 create a new revision every time you edit a node? This was an option in Drupal 6 but not 7.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just like in Drupal 6, you enable this in the content type settings. At admin/structure/types, click edit for the content type you want to enable this and then check "[] Create new revision" under Publishing options.

Comment: What about if there is a role has Administer contents permissions and the adminostrtor wants to force the revision regardless any one else decision about it?

Comment: Then you must have only 1 super admin, and make roles for the other users, but these other roles must not have the ability to manage revisions or do any revisions actions. Then they wont be able to unselect it.